# Pycups on Bitnami Odoo Stack

Tags: python, odoo, cups

Hi I am trying to install pycups in my Windows 8 PC. But don't Know how to do it. I am getting an error :

```
C:\Users\Manish>pip install pycups
Collecting pycups
  Using cached pycups-1.9.70.tar.bz2
Installing collected packages: pycups
  Running setup.py install for pycups
    building 'cups' extension
    C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Pytho
n\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DVERSION="1.9.70
" -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tccupsmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64
-2.7\Release\cupsmodule.obj
    cupsmodule.c
    cupsmodule.c(23) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cups/cups.h
': No such file or directory
    error: command '"C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Vis
ual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2
    Complete output from command C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, t
okenize;__file__='c:\\users\\manish\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-zkldnw\\pyc
ups\\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().rep
lace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\manish\appdata
\local\temp\pip-rcpejp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-man
aged --compile:
running install

running build

running build_ext

building 'cups' extension

creating build

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7

creating build\temp.win-amd64-2.7\Release

    C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Pytho
n\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -DVERSION="1.9.70
" -IC:\Python27\include -IC:\Python27\PC /Tccupsmodule.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64
-2.7\Release\cupsmodule.obj

    cupsmodule.c

    cupsmodule.c(23) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cups/cups.h
': No such file or directory

    error: command '"C:\Users\Manish\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Vis
ual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe"' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
    Command "C:\Python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='c:
\\users\\manish\\appdata\\local\\temp\\pip-build-zkldnw\\pycups\\setup.py';exec(
compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'),
__file__, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\manish\appdata\local\temp\pip-rcpe
jp-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" fail
ed with error code 1 in c:\users\manish\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-zkldnw\pycu
ps
```

Please help

I also tried bitnami Odoo v8 Stack. But same problem as i dont know how to add pycups module. Bitnami has its own environment.
Thanks

Comment: i think you are trying to extract .bz2 in Windows machine! as per my knowledge, which is not possible!

Comment: download windows compatible package and then try to install

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer [pycups](https://code.activestate.com/pypm/pycups/) Documentation.

As there is no available package for Windows right now, You can not run in windows machine. Try in Mac OS or any *NIX environment. You can not install linux packages into Windows!